# how to hide some section in crystal report if it has no value to show?

Tags: crystal-reports

im having trouble to achieve this thing..how can i hide a section in crystal report if it has no value to show ? i want to hide the detail section A..that section contains is sub-report..

[image]

coz it takes so much space when i view my report and it kinda lookin very ugly..lol

[image]

glad for any help..tnx :)

Answer (score 2):

You can right click the section, click section expert, click the suppress checkbox, then the suppress formula button. In the formula section, enter a condition that will result in an empty sub-report. Click save and close.

Also select the suppress blank section checkbox

You can also do the same by selecting the sub-report, click format sub-report and in the sub-report tab, select the checkbox that says suppress blank sub report. This may depend on the version off Crystal you have.

Comment: i'll try that out mate :)

Comment: btw..how to do that ? the condition thingy in the formula ? :)

Comment: So if in your sub report it gets data based on a where cause you can create a formula with the same condition, or count of that condition